# What is HTTP tunneling?

Tags: networking, network-protocols

Yesterday, I was interviewed by one of the company for UI development. The point is the interviewer asked one important question `what is HTTP tunneling`. 
I've never come across this info on UI stuffs such as javascript, HTML and jquery.

Comment: I think it is in line with HTTP as a protocol and not specific to either HTML, JS or jQuery

Comment: Add other relevant tags in your question to get more concrete answers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

HTTP tunneling is used to bypass firewalls and other network restrictions and an HTTP tunnel is used to create a direct network link between two locations.

A tunnel is used to ship a foreign protocol across a network that normally wouldn’t support it. You can take protocol A and wrap it or put it in a tunnel with protocol B.

Answer (score 5):

Tunneling::

Tunneling, also known as “port forwarding,” is the method of transmitting private network data and protocol information through public network by encapsulating the data.

What is HTTP Tunneling?

HTTP tunneling is the process in which communications are encapsulated by using HTTP protocol.

How do I achieve It:

HTTP tunneling is designed mainly for firewall aversion. HTTP tunneling performs protocol encapsulation, by enclosing data packets of one protocol (SOAP, JRMP, etc.) within HTTP Packets. The HTTP packets are then sent across the firewall as normal internet traffic

Answer (score 1):

Http tunneling overcomes limitation set by your company (in corporates), and by ISP (at home). Http is wrapped over your request and tunneled through to the end server.

Suppose you want to access some websites that are blocked by firewall; you will need a http tunnel server outside of the firewall. Your request will be wrapped by http protocol till the http tunnel server and will be sent to the website on your behalf. In this way your requests can be hidden underneath the http protocol.